# Store values from file in arrays depending a value in the array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, file

Hello everyone i am new in java .I want to write a programm that reads from a file and by a specific way.My file is mix with strings and ints.
In the first line there is a number that tell us how many lines will follow.
After this, in each line there will be a String and an int.The int value will tell us how many values there are in this line.
For example :
text file:

```
2
Coffee       2  Water 200   cofe 300
SweetCoffee  3  Water 200   cofe 300   Sugar 10
```

I want to pass values in different arrays.

```
   nameOfProduct[0]=Coffee
   nameOfProduct[1]=SweetCoffee  
   numofIngredients[0]=2
   element[0][0]=water
   element[0][1]=cofe
   element[1][3]=sugar
```

i try to find a way that works.This is what i have done until now

```
package pkg1;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class readfile {


    private Scanner x;
    int count=0;    
    int i,j,noIngredients;


    public void openfile() {
        try {
            x = new Scanner(new File("MyRecipes.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("could not find the file");
        }
    }



    public void readFile() {
        i=0;
        int numofRecipes = x.nextInt();

        String nameOfProduct[] = new String[numofRecipes];
        int numofIngredients[]  = new int[numofRecipes];


        while (x.hasNext()) {
        //   String line = x.nextLine();
            nameOfProduct[i] = x.next();

            numofIngredients[i] = x.nextInt();

            noIngredients=numofIngredients[i];

            String element[][] = new String[numofRecipes][noIngredients];

            int quantity[][] = new int[numofRecipes][noIngredients];

            System.out.printf("%s %d ",nameOfProduct,numofIngredients);

            j=0;

            while( x.hasNext() || x.hasNextInt())  {
                element[i][j] = x.next();
                quantity[i][j] = x.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("%s %d ",element[i][j],quantity[i][j]);
                j++;
            }
            i++; 
            x.nextLine() ;  
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: i'd create an object called a Recipe, and inside it contains Ingredients. It will simplify things greatly instead of using a bunch of matching arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Change this : `while( x.hasNext() || x.hasNextInt())`
to: `for (int k=0; k<numofIngredients[i]; k++)`
and replace j with k inside the loop

and `while (x.hasNext())`(The first while loop in readFile()) 
to: `for (int tot=0; tot<numOfRecipes; tot++){`

Rest is fine I believe.

But yeah, as RAZ_Muh_Taz said, make a Recipe class to get a neater version of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type with scanner class. Where you write `x.next()` there you can write:
`if(x.hasNextInt()
  int k = x.nextInt()
 else String s = x.next()`

You can always check type and for more types you can check java libarary.